# how to find overlapping and inner bounding boxes from a outer bounding box?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, bounding-box

I am trying to annotate a image and here is the `one` bounding box details from a annotation I have made,

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oisK7.jpg) - The annotations are based on this document image.

```
# annotation
{'x': 267.9,
 'y': 40.3,
 'height': 116.7,
 'width': 672.7,
 'center': [604.25, 98.65],
 'points': [[267.9, 40.3], [267.9, 157], [940.6, 157], [940.6, 40.3]]}
```

Now I have five other small bounding boxes which are also annotated by me,

```
[{'x': 290,
  'y': 66,
  'width': 309,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [444.5, 102.0],
  'points': [[290.0, 66.0], [290.0, 138.0], [599.0, 138.0], [599.0, 66.0]]},
 {'x': 626,
  'y': 68,
  'width': 295,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [773.5, 104.0],
  'points': [[626.0, 68.0], [626.0, 140.0], [921.0, 140.0], [921.0, 68.0]]},
 {'x': 960,
  'y': 69,
  'width': 20,
  'height': 71,
  'center': [970.0, 104.5],
  'points': [[960.0, 69.0], [960.0, 140.0], [980.0, 140.0], [980.0, 69.0]]},
 {'x': 1000,
  'y': 72,
  'width': 881,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [1440.5, 108.0],
  'points': [[1000.0, 72.0], [1000.0, 144.0], [1881.0, 144.0], [1881.0, 72.0]]},
 {'x': 1904,
  'y': 73,
  'width': 5,
  'height': 71,
  'center': [1906.5, 108.5],
  'points': [[1904.0, 73.0], [1904.0, 144.0], [1909.0, 144.0], [1909.0, 73.0]]}
 ]
```

I am looking for a way to find how many of the above 5 bounding box coordinates overlap or come inside the first main bounding box that I have at the very top.

I also need an option to select how much percent of overlapping to consider it as overlap. Let's say if two boxes are slightly touching I don't want them. Atleast 10-15% of bbox should be insider to consider it overlapping or inside.

Can anyone help me out on how I can achieve that?

**Desired Output:**

In my example, these two below smaller bounding boxes are inside or overlapping with the main bounding box.

```
[{'x': 290,
  'y': 66,
  'width': 309,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [444.5, 102.0],
  'points': [[290.0, 66.0], [290.0, 138.0], [599.0, 138.0], [599.0, 66.0]]},
 {'x': 626,
  'y': 68,
  'width': 295,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [773.5, 104.0],
  'points': [[626.0, 68.0], [626.0, 140.0], [921.0, 140.0], [921.0, 68.0]]}]
```

The function I used to create `points` for bounding box from `center points, width, height` is this,

```
def convert_points(center_x, center_y, width, height):
    x = center_x
    y = center_y
    return [[x - width / 2, y - height / 2], [x - width / 2, y + height / 2],
            [x + width / 2, y + height / 2], [x + width / 2, y - height / 2]]
```

Comment: in C++ you can use use opencv Rect intersection (&& operator) to test if they overlap.  Maybe there is a python function as well

Comment: @Micka if you come across anything can you provide a answer to helpout.

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/90455/how-to-perform-intersection-or-union-operations-on-a-rect-in-python/

Answer (score 3):

You can check to see if two boxes have any overlap by checking if any of the corners of one box fall within the bounds of the other box (you have to do this vice-versa as well).

```py
# check if a point falls within bounds
def inBounds(point, tl, br):
    x, y = point;
    left, top = tl;
    right, bottom = br;
    if left < x and x < right and top < y and y < bottom:
        return True;
    return False;

# check if these two boxes have any overlap
def boxOverlap(box1, box2):
    # check box2 in box1
    tl = box1[0];
    br = box1[2];
    for point in box2:
        if inBounds(point, tl, br):
            return True;
    
    # check box1 in box2
    tl = box2[0];
    br = box2[2];
    for point in box1:
        if inBounds(point, tl, br):
            return True;

    # no overlap
    return False;
```

Edit:

Sorry, to clarify: I'm thinking of boxes as four points [top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left] and I assume the boxes aren't rotated or anything (I think that's a safe assumption for most annotations).

Edit 2:

Here's an example of how to use this. Remember: I don't know all of the different ways you're going to use this. You'll have to modify it for your own use if you find something that isn't working.

```py
# main box annotation
main_annot = {'x': 267.9,
 'y': 40.3,
 'height': 116.7,
 'width': 672.7,
 'center': [604.25, 98.65],
 'points': [[267.9, 40.3], [267.9, 157], [940.6, 157], [940.6, 40.3]]};

# other box annotation
other_annot = {'x': 290,
  'y': 66,
  'width': 309,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [444.5, 102.0],
  'points': [[290.0, 66.0], [290.0, 138.0], [599.0, 138.0], [599.0, 66.0]]};

if boxOverlap(main_annot['points'], other_annot['points']):
    print("OVERLAP DETECTED");
else:
    print("NO OVERLAP");
```

Edit 3:

WOOPS! I just thought of a case where this function doesn't work. Please disregard this answer for now. I don't have much time left today to work on this. If I come up with another answer later I'll post it, but for now you shouldn't use this. Sorry, I should've been more diligent with checking edge cases.

Edit 4:

Ok, I looked up an actual algorithm this time instead of trying to make one on the spot.

```py
# check if these two boxes have any overlap
def boxOverlap(box1, box2):
    # get corners
    tl1 = box1[0];
    br1 = box1[2];
    tl2 = box2[0];
    br2 = box2[2];

    # separating axis theorem
    # left/right
    if tl1[0] >= br2[0] or tl2[0] >= br1[0]:
        return False;

    # top/down
    if tl1[1] >= br2[1] or tl2[1] >= br1[1]:
        return False;

    # overlap
    return True;

# main box annotation
main_annot = {'x': 267.9,
 'y': 40.3,
 'height': 116.7,
 'width': 672.7,
 'center': [604.25, 98.65],
 'points': [[267.9, 40.3], [267.9, 157], [940.6, 157], [940.6, 40.3]]};

# other box annotation
other_annot = {'x': 290,
  'y': 66,
  'width': 309,
  'height': 72,
  'center': [444.5, 102.0],
  'points': [[290.0, 66.0], [290.0, 138.0], [599.0, 138.0], [599.0, 66.0]]};

if boxOverlap(main_annot['points'], other_annot['points']):
    print("OVERLAP DETECTED");
else:
    print("NO OVERLAP");
```

Here's the source I pulled the equation from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-rectangles-overlap/

That was pretty embarrassing, I should've just used an established algorithm to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain what exactly you mean by rotated? My document images are always straight.

Comment: by 'not-rotated' I assume that the for the top-left and top-right corners the y-value is the same. Ditto for the y-value of the bottom-right and bottom-left. All of your boxes seem to follow this rule so I think all of your boxes are flat which is fine. I just mentioned rotations because the functions above only work if the boxes are flat.

Comment: Got it, Also, I have tried the code but I am getting `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object`, I tried with `box1` is the main box and box2 is other boxes to compare. Can you test it out once.

Comment: can you post how you're calling the function? remember: I'm assuming that the boxes you're feeding into the function are of this form: [top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left]. So for the main box you're feeding in this: [[267.9, 40.3], [267.9, 157], [940.6, 157], [940.6, 40.3]]

Comment: judging from the error you got my rough guess is that the error occured at the "x, y = point" line which could happen if you put the entire annotation in as box1. The function just wants the "points" section of each annotation.

Comment: The error you mentioned is correct, Can you please provide an example execution code based on my annotation bounding boxes I gave above so I can understand it, which inputs to use as arguments in the function.

Comment: Sure, please do help me out when you have some time.

Comment: can you please tell me whether the points in my bounding boxes are `[top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left]`, can you check my `convert_points` function in my question and see if its correct, Because I generated those points myself.

Comment: It looks like your points are set up as [top-left, bottom-left, bottom-right, top-left]. This is fine. The function is really just looking for top-left (the lowest x and y) and bottom-right (the highest x and y). So long as those two points are where they should be then it should work. Still, take my answer with a grain of salt, I already messed up once. Try it out, think of edge cases to see if it breaks anywhere.

Comment: I will try to check for edge cases, but i am not very familiar with these, if you have time to think on any cases where this may fail please do update.

Comment: If I am right, then this code will return if one bounding box line is just touching the other bounding box line and count it as overlap right, but I need something to overlap only if one is inside overlap atleast 5-10% inside. Can you help me to modify it.

Comment: you're correct. The separating axis theorem only states whether or not they overlap, it doesn't give any sense for how much they overlap and isn't useful for your current requirements. Since you need to know how much they overlap, you could figure out the rectangle for the overlapped region by marking out the intersections of the rectangle lines. This would give you an easy way to calculate the area of the overlap and check against your requirements. I probably won't be able to work on this at all today, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Sure, I will try to figure it out, if you have some time anytime please do help me out. I have been struggling with this problem for more than a week now.

Comment: There is a source of confusion in the variable naming: namely for you in this context "top" means numerically lower... In other contexts top means numerically higher... Walked into this when I lifted the code for some geo-coordinate bounding boxes :-)

Comment: ah, true, I've gotten too used to using it like that. That's a convention from image processing; image origin is top-left